# How to make a floating toolbar?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2012

I have my window, now I want to create a toolbar, which I could drag anywhere and populate it, does anybody know what is the correct way of naming this process? and maybe some tutorials or books how can I achieve it in C++/VS12?

Comment: Are you using some framework/toolkit (e.g., Qt or MFC) or the raw Win32 API, or what?

Comment: I'm using raw Win32 API, is it possible? or should I use Qt?

Comment: With the raw API, a floating toolbar is just another window. In it, you display something like a bitmap of the images of the "tools". When you get a mouse click, you compute which tool's image was clicked, and act accordingly. I'm not exactly a huge fan of Qt, but it does make a lot of things like this quite a bit easier (especially if you might ever want to port your code to some other OS).

Comment: ahuh, I had a hunch that I will have to do another window. Though I'm clueless about the setting, of the window class. Could you give some code for example?

Comment: I don't think I have any code handy (last time I did a toolbar using the raw API was probably at least 10 years ago).

Comment: hahahaha, what's the modern best way of doing it?

Comment: Well, pretty much every framework/toolkit supports them. Of those, I suppose Qt is the most "modern", though that may be open to argument.

Comment: Thank your answers were the most helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look for GUI design library. if you want to do it in C++, i will suggest you to use QT.